# subprocess.check_output good for multi-threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I'm to find a way to do multi-threading with subprocess library of python, here is what i would do to start several ping at the same time:

output_1 = subprocess.check_output(['ping','-c','5','8.8.8.8'])

output_2 = subprocess.check_output(['ping','-c','5','198.35.26.96'])

it works, but i'm wondering if the 2 subprocesses are proceeded at the same time or one after the other. Any idea ?

Cheers

Aurel

Comment: These commands will be executed sequentially. If you want multithreaded functionality, take a look at the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) and [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) packages.

Comment: Thanks, actually i used Popen with a table of commands as input, seems to work..